# Filter build steps by branch google cloud plateform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-repository

I have the below steps

```
steps:
  # This step show the version of Gradle
  - id: Gradle Install
    name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
    entrypoint: gradle
    args: ["--version"]

  # This step build the gradle application
  - id: Build
    name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
    entrypoint: gradle
    args: ["build"]

  # This step run test
  - id: Publish
    name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
    entrypoint: gradle
    args: ["publish"]
```

The last step I want to do only on **MASTER** branch

Found one link related to this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/138

Its using a `bash` command, how can I put the gradle command inside the bash.

**Update**

After the suggestion answer I have updated the steps as

```
  - id: Publish
    name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
    entrypoint: "bash"
    args:
    - "-c"
    - |
      [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "develop" ]] && gradle publish
```

The build pipeline failed with below exception

```
Starting Step #2 - "Publish"
Step #2 - "Publish": Already have image: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
Finished Step #2 - "Publish"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 2 "gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine" failed: starting step container failed: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

Comment: You may be able to use something like this:
`
- id: Publish
  name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
  entrypoint: sh
  args:
  - c
  - |
  [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "master" ]] && gradle publish"
`

Answer (score 2):

The suggested solution didn't work for me, I have to write the below code

```
  # This step run test
  - id: Publish
    name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine
    entrypoint: "sh"
    args:
      - -c
      - |
        if [ $BRANCH_NAME == 'master' ]
        then
          echo "Branch is = $BRANCH_NAME"
          gradle publish
        fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Current workarounds are mentioned as following :

1. Using different cloudbuild.yaml files for each branch
2. Overriding entrypoint and injecting bash as mentioned in the [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/138#issuecomment-340525227):

> steps:
>
> ```
> - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
>   entrypoint: 'bash'
>   args:
>   - '-c'
>   - |
>     echo "Here's a convenient pattern to use for embedding shell scripts in cloudbuild.yaml."
>     echo "This step only pushes an image if this build was triggered by a push to master."
>     [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "master" ]] && docker push gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/image
> ```

This [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/gitops-cloud-build) outlines an alternative where you check in different cloudbuild.yaml files on different development branches.

You can try the following for Gradle command as mentioned by bhito:

> ```
> - id: Publish 
> name: gradle:7.4.2-jdk17-alpine 
> entrypoint: sh 
> args: - c 
> - | 
> [[ "$BRANCH_NAME" == "master" ]] && gradle publish
> ```

Cloud build provides configuring triggers by branch, tag, and pr . This lets you define different build configs to use for different repo events, e.g. one for prs, another for deploying to prod, etc.you can refer to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/automating-builds/create-manage-triggers) on how to create and manage triggers.

you can check this [blog](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/devops-sre/cloud-build-brings-advanced-cicd-capabilities-to-github)  for more updates on additional features and can go through the [release notes](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/release-notes)  for more Cloud build updates.
To gain some more insights  on Gradle, you can refer to the [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gradle)

Comment: I have update the question in the update section, can you please have a look. It is not working